# How to use MarkLogic xquery to tell if a document is 'in-memory'

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to tell if an XML document has been constructed (e.g. using `xdmp:unquote`) or has been retrieved from a database. One method I have tried is to check the document-uri property

```
declare variable $doc as document-node() external;

if (fn:exists(fn:document-uri($doc))) then
  'on database'
else
  'in memory'
```

This seems to work well enough but I can't see anything in the MarkLogic documentation that guarantees this. Is this method reliable? Is there some other technique I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

I think that behavior has been stable for a while. You could always check for the URI too, as long as you expect it to be from the current database:

```
xdmp:exists(fn:doc(fn:document-uri($doc)))
```

Or if you are in an update context and need ACID guarantees, use `fn:exists`.

The real test would be to try to call `xdmp:node-replace` or similar, and catch the expected error. Those node-level update functions do not work on constructed nodes. But that requires an update context, and might be tricky to implement in a robust way.

Comment: Checking for the URI in the database is not the test I want to do. A bit of context might explain better. I'm working in a framework I can't change. This framework does some simple version control by calling a 'getVersion' function on two documents, the incoming document and the existing document on the database. My case is unusual in the in order to get the correct version control I need to know within the 'getVersion' function whether I'm dealing with the incoming document or the existing document.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I thought of node-replace but it's a bit clumsy. It's a shame there isn't some official function to explicitly check for a constructed node.

Comment: Hmmm... that versioning mechanism sounds awkward. Have you consulted the framework author?

Answer (score 1):

If your XML document is `in-memeory`, you can use `in-mem-update` API

`import module namespace mem        = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update"     at  "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy";`

If your XML document exists in your database you can use `fn:exists()` or `fn:doc-available()`

Answer (score 0):

The real test of In-memory or In-Db is **xdmp:node-replace** .

If you are able to replace , update , delete a node then it is in database else if it throws exception then it's not in database.

Now there are two situation

**1. your document is not created at all:** 
   you can use `fn:empty()` to check if it is created or not.

**2. Your document is created and it's in memory:**
   if `fn:empty()` returns false and xdmp:node-replace throws exception then it's in-memory